# GPU uses only one fan

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan, temperature

i have the nvidia geforce gtx 1060 3gb which has **2 fans** and i saw that **only the one** spins.

My GPU temperature is 55 when i run only a broswer and when i play a game it is 65-70. Is it ok ? And if so, why only the one fan spins? (My desktop is clear and there is no dust there).

Can i fix something easily or i have to replace the gpu(or only the fan) ?

Answer (score 0):

The temperatures are ok, however, that isn't normal that only one fan is spinning. The fans should be connected so they both should spin.

Check first that nothing is touching the fan preventing it to spin. You may have to replace the faulty fan, which is luckily easy, I have done those replacements many times. If the card is till under warranty you should take it back to shop.